# Get list of groups-users-permissions-special permission for a folder in Windows 2003, programatically

Tags: c#, security, permissions, ntfs

I use Window 2003 server, and I need get information about security folder, programatically using C#.

I want create a tool for check permissions. I need get the groups, users, permissions and special permissions for a folder,

> C:\Documents and Settings\All
>   Users\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

edit:

the following is a sample code for the GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm method.

```
public static string GetObjectPermission(string fullFolderName)
{
    FileSecurity fileSecure = File.GetAccessControl(fullFolderName);
    StringBuilder acer = new StringBuilder();
    fileSecure.GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(AccessControlSections.All);

    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ace in fileSecure.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
    {
        acer.Append(ace.FileSystemRights + ":" + ' ' + ace.IdentityReference.Value + "\n");
    }
    return acer.ToString();
}
```

This sample code will show you which NTAccount can modify or read the folder, such as this function.

How can I get groups and special permissions ??

Any sample code, suggestions?

Comment: When you say "Get special permissions" do you want to just know if they have them, or what they actually are?

Comment: I want know if they actually have what permissions.

Comment: Ah, ok. Because it is easy to tell if they would check that boxes in Windows Explorer for Special permissions, because it returns a negative number. But it is a little more complicated to associate each part of that number with the permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use DirectoryInfo to get the ACL's? All ACL's should be in there (user, group):

```
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the  
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
```

Full docs:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f66bc2(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f66bc2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all ace list  in ACL on folder,you should use this method, also with this method you can access other ace properties, like 
 ***ace.AccessControlType*** ,  ***ace.IsInherited***;

```
 public static void checkAceInformation(string fileName,string loginName)
        {
            string fileSystemRightsValue = "";

            FileSecurity security = File.GetAccessControl(FileName);

            AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

            foreach(FileSystemAccessRule ace in acl)
            {
                if(ace.IdentityReference.Value == LoginName)
                {
                    fileSystemRightsValue = ace.FileSystemRights.ToString();

                    Console.WriteLine(LoginName +  "  your permission value is" + fileSystemRightsValue)

                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(LoginName + "your not permission in this folder");

        }
```